# Change position through DOM EVENT FLOW - Jquery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom-events, target

I want to change the `<div>` position after the user stops dragging it. Also the number `10` without commas doesn't work.

It does change to a blue color, but the position doesn't. What can I do?
I have a lot of `.screen` divs. Thanks!

```js
$('.screen').draggable({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    if (parseInt(event.target.offsetTop) < -1) {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      event.target.style.offsetTop = "10";
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried event.target.offsetTop = "10"

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Are you sure? I tried and it doesn't work. Also in the dom, it's written without any kind of units.

Comment: @BerkÖztürk Doesn't work. This way you lose the correct path to the attribute.

Comment: `offsetTop` isn't a property of the `style` object, it's on the element directly, eg `event.target.offsetTop = 10`

Comment: @Yopi offsetTop is not a style attribute. You want to do event.target.style.top = "10px"?

Comment: @BerkÖztürk Yes, for example. I just want to succeed to move the ```div``` position through the DOM. After that, I play with the number. But It doesn't work. I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two main issues here. Firstly `offsetTop` is a property of the Element object, not the `style` of the Element.

Secondly `offsetTop` is *readonly*, so you cannot use it to update the position of the element. To do that you need to set `style.top`:

```js
$('.screen').draggable({
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    if (event.target.offsetTop < -1) {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      event.target.style.top = '10px';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<div class="screen">Drag me</div>
```

Also note that `offsetTop` returns an integer value, so `parseInt()` is not required.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!!!!!!!!!!! It worked very well. Just question for future: How to know what can I only read and what can I change. Any list on the internet?

Comment: Yes, refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). In this case if you look at the docs for [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) you can see it states that it's readonly